# How to make sound effects?

Tags: sound-effects

I wanna know how to create sound effects like this: http://vocaroo.com/i/s0TwP1pr52yw

it's a part from Zedd - Rude (remix)

I can't find any video tutorials on youtube that shows how to make SFX... all I find is about making melody with FL STUDIO

Comment: Not sure I heard a sound effect just a synth.

Comment: There are a lot of sounds in that short clip. Are you referring to the dub step'ish synth melody, the mellow stringy chords, the boomy kickdrum blast, the bassline or or the cymbals?

Answer (score 1):

First off, split everything up. Drums are drums. Bass is bass. Guitar is guitar. And any crazy sounds are most likely synths. Research synthesizers. Get a copy of FL Studio or Reason. Try adding FX to normal piano or guitar sounds. FX can be added to drums, bass, piano, guitar... anything really.

To be a little more clear, think of a guitar pedal. If you play it without the pedal it's a "clean" guitar tone. Once you hook up the pedals (the FX) suddenly you have sound effects.

So, to make sound effects you need an initial source (an instrument) and then you need an FX pedal, rack, or plug-in. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found Native Instruments Massive is good for creating good Fx.
Its a complex MIDI plugin for your DAW, I would highly recommend you check it out.